# Problems with code compiling on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to compile the example code from Jansson Tutorial Page:
https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

When I try to build the project Visual Studio 2013 returns the following errors:
Error   11  error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _json_array_get referenced in function _wmain
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _json_array_size referenced in function _wmain
Error   10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _json_loads referenced in function _wmain
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _json_object_get referenced in function _wmain
Error   9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _json_string_value referenced in function _wmain

I tried to find whete the problem is but, I can not find any any helpful information on the internet.

Here is the code sample from the problems:

```
for (i = 0; i < json_array_size(root); i++)
{
    json_t *data, *sha, *commit, *message;
    const char *message_text;

    data = json_array_get(root, i);
    if (!json_is_object(data))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: commit data %d is not an object\n", (int)(i + 1));
        json_decref(root);
        return 1;
    }

    sha = json_object_get(data, "sha");
    if (!json_is_string(sha))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: commit %d: sha is not a string\n", (int)(i + 1));
        return 1;
    }

    commit = json_object_get(data, "commit");
    if (!json_is_object(commit))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: commit %d: commit is not an object\n", (int)(i + 1));
        json_decref(root);
        return 1;
    }

    message = json_object_get(commit, "message");
    if (!json_is_string(message))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: commit %d: message is not a string\n", (int)(i + 1));
        json_decref(root);
        return 1;
    }

    message_text = json_string_value(message);
    printf("%.8s %.*s\n", json_string_value(sha), message_text);
}

json_decref(root);
return 0;
```

Also I have uploaded the whole project in GitHub:
https://github.com/mariopavlov/C/tree/master/ExampleJson

Could you please help me to fix these problems?

Thank you in advance,
Mario.

Comment: Did you add the json library to your linker options?

Comment: Yes under Configuration Properties --> Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies, I have added the .lib file: jansson.lib

Comment: Looks like you're still missing some json library, or is this one you mentioned self contained?

Comment: According to Jansson web site I need to compile the lib file from the source, which I have done, and also I have added the library file to my linker options. And the second instruction from the website is to add jansson.h file, which is located in my project folder, and it is added to my project.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this. I have the same error message having done the same compile and link steps.